# Kubernetes: problems with reaching service cluster IPs

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed a master and a worker node on two private openstack cloud instances using the instructions from http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/

The problem is that when I send a request to a service, the service only succesfully forwards to pods deployed on the local node. The remote pods are however reachable by their respective cluster IP.

For example the mongo service consists of one pod that is deployed on the worker node.

```
ubuntu@kube-master:~$ kubectl get services
NAME         CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
kubernetes   10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP     18h
mongo        10.0.0.208   nodes         27017/TCP   17h
nginx        10.0.0.85    <none>        80/TCP      17h
```

As can be shown below: the pod IP is reachable but the pod is not reachable via the service IP

```
ubuntu@kube-master:~$ kubectl describe pods -l name=mongo | grep IP
IP:             10.1.78.2
ubuntu@kube-master:~$ curl 10.1.78.2:27017
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.

ubuntu@kube-master:~$ curl 10.0.0.208:27017 --verbose
* Rebuilt URL to: 10.0.0.208:27017/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 10.0.0.208...
```

I have tried to resolve this problem by starting the kube-proxy with the "proxy-mode=iptables" option but this does not make sense because the service IP does not match a subnet-mask from the route table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         host-172-17-13- 0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.1.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 flannel.1
10.1.58.0       *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 docker0
169.254.169.254 host-172-17-13- 255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
172.17.13.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

I have also started the master and worker with the following options set

```
K8S_VERSION is set to: 1.2.3
ETCD_VERSION is set to: 2.2.1
FLANNEL_VERSION is set to: 0.5.5
FLANNEL_IFACE is set to: eth0
FLANNEL_IPMASQ is set to: false
```

The logs from the kube-proxy are as follows:

```
Flag --resource-container has been deprecated, This feature will be removed in a later release.
I0511 15:21:07.898497       1 iptables.go:177] Could not connect to D-Bus system bus: dial unix /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: connect: no such file or directory
I0511 15:21:07.901068       1 server.go:163] Running in resource-only container "\"\""
E0511 15:21:07.905001       1 server.go:341] Can't get Node "kube-master", assuming iptables proxy, err: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/nodes/kube-master: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
I0511 15:21:07.907082       1 server.go:201] Using iptables Proxier.
I0511 15:21:07.907168       1 proxier.go:208] missing br-netfilter module or unset br-nf-call-iptables; proxy may not work as intended
I0511 15:21:07.907207       1 server.go:214] Tearing down userspace rules.
I0511 15:21:07.928371       1 conntrack.go:36] Setting nf_conntrack_max to 262144
I0511 15:21:07.928436       1 conntrack.go:41] Setting conntrack hashsize to 65536
E0511 15:21:07.928693       1 reflector.go:205] pkg/proxy/config/api.go:30: Failed to list *api.Service: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
E0511 15:21:07.928754       1 reflector.go:205] pkg/proxy/config/api.go:33: Failed to list *api.Endpoints: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/endpoints?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
I0511 15:21:07.933435       1 conntrack.go:46] Setting nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established to 86400
E0511 15:21:07.934083       1 event.go:207] Unable to write event: 'Post http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/events: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused' (may retry after sleeping)
E0511 15:21:08.929506       1 reflector.go:205] pkg/proxy/config/api.go:33: Failed to list *api.Endpoints: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/endpoints?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
E0511 15:21:08.929517       1 reflector.go:205] pkg/proxy/config/api.go:30: Failed to list *api.Service: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
E0511 15:21:09.930126       1 reflector.go:205] pkg/proxy/config/api.go:33: Failed to list *api.Endpoints: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/endpoints?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
E0511 15:21:09.930421       1 reflector.go:205] pkg/proxy/config/api.go:30: Failed to list *api.Service: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
E0511 15:21:10.930876       1 reflector.go:205] pkg/proxy/config/api.go:30: Failed to list *api.Service: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
E0511 15:21:10.931430       1 reflector.go:205] pkg/proxy/config/api.go:33: Failed to list *api.Endpoints: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/endpoints?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
I0511 15:21:11.937568       1 proxier.go:501] Setting endpoints for "default/kubernetes:https" to [172.17.13.43:6443]
I0511 15:21:11.938752       1 proxier.go:501] Setting endpoints for "default/mongo:" to [10.1.78.2:27017]
I0511 15:21:11.939017       1 proxier.go:501] Setting endpoints for "default/nginx:" to [10.1.58.2:80 10.1.58.3:80 10.1.78.3:80]
I0511 15:21:11.939396       1 proxier.go:646] Not syncing iptables until Services and Endpoints have been received from master
I0511 15:21:11.940217       1 proxier.go:426] Adding new service "default/nginx:" at 10.0.0.85:80/TCP
I0511 15:21:11.940376       1 proxier.go:426] Adding new service "default/kubernetes:https" at 10.0.0.1:443/TCP
I0511 15:21:11.940433       1 proxier.go:426] Adding new service "default/mongo:" at 10.0.0.208:27017/TCP
I0511 15:21:11.956264       1 proxier.go:1197] Opened local port "nodePort for default/mongo:" (:31278/tcp)
I0511 15:21:12.773826       1 proxier.go:501] Setting endpoints for "default/nginx:" to [10.1.78.3:80]
I0511 15:21:19.590803       1 proxier.go:501] Setting endpoints for "default/nginx:" to [10.1.58.2:80 10.1.78.3:80]
I0511 15:21:21.798255       1 proxier.go:501] Setting endpoints for "default/nginx:" to [10.1.58.2:80 10.1.58.4:80 10.1.78.3:80]
I0511 15:21:21.833021       1 proxier.go:501] Setting endpoints for "default/nginx:" to [10.1.58.4:80 10.1.78.3:80]
I0511 15:21:25.457793       1 proxier.go:501] Setting endpoints for "default/nginx:" to [10.1.58.4:80 10.1.58.5:80 10.1.78.3:80]
I0511 15:21:25.515718       1 proxier.go:501] Setting endpoints for "default/nginx:" to [10.1.58.4:80 10.1.58.5:80]
I0511 15:21:27.410673       1 proxier.go:501] Setting endpoints for "default/nginx:" to [10.1.58.4:80 10.1.58.5:80 10.1.78.4:80]
```

What could be the problem?

Eddy

P.S.

The iptables-save command shows the following output

```
root@kube-master:/home/ubuntu# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed May 11 17:06:57 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:KUBE-MARK-MASQ - [0:0]
:KUBE-NODEPORTS - [0:0]
:KUBE-POSTROUTING - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-55NY7Y2VS7MU5SHC - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-INQ4JU67KGX5TI3V - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-J3MBDOP5WNYLP73O - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-MMF6BX4SIRXFC7EI - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-THKIU3KIDKH63VHE - [0:0]
:KUBE-SERVICES - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-4N57TFCL4MD7ZTDA - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-G2OJTDIWIJ7HQ7MY - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes postrouting rules" -j KUBE-POSTROUTING
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.58.0/24 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.78.0/24 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A KUBE-MARK-MASQ -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4000/0x4000
-A KUBE-NODEPORTS -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongo:" -m tcp --dport 31278 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-NODEPORTS -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongo:" -m tcp --dport 31278 -j KUBE-SVC-G2OJTDIWIJ7HQ7MY
-A KUBE-POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service traffic requiring SNAT" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j MASQUERADE
-A KUBE-SEP-55NY7Y2VS7MU5SHC -s 10.1.58.4/32 -m comment --comment "default/nginx:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-55NY7Y2VS7MU5SHC -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/nginx:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.58.4:80
-A KUBE-SEP-INQ4JU67KGX5TI3V -s 10.1.78.4/32 -m comment --comment "default/nginx:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-INQ4JU67KGX5TI3V -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/nginx:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.78.4:80
-A KUBE-SEP-J3MBDOP5WNYLP73O -s 10.1.78.2/32 -m comment --comment "default/mongo:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-J3MBDOP5WNYLP73O -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongo:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.78.2:27017
-A KUBE-SEP-MMF6BX4SIRXFC7EI -s 10.1.58.5/32 -m comment --comment "default/nginx:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-MMF6BX4SIRXFC7EI -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/nginx:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.58.5:80
-A KUBE-SEP-THKIU3KIDKH63VHE -s 172.17.13.43/32 -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-THKIU3KIDKH63VHE -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.13.43:6443
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.0.0.85/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/nginx: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 80 -j KUBE-SVC-4N57TFCL4MD7ZTDA
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.0.0.208/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongo: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 27017 -j KUBE-SVC-G2OJTDIWIJ7HQ7MY
-A KUBE-SERVICES -m comment --comment "kubernetes service nodeports; NOTE: this must be the last rule in this chain" -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j KUBE-NODEPORTS
-A KUBE-SVC-4N57TFCL4MD7ZTDA -m comment --comment "default/nginx:" -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.33332999982 -j KUBE-SEP-55NY7Y2VS7MU5SHC
-A KUBE-SVC-4N57TFCL4MD7ZTDA -m comment --comment "default/nginx:" -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-MMF6BX4SIRXFC7EI
-A KUBE-SVC-4N57TFCL4MD7ZTDA -m comment --comment "default/nginx:" -j KUBE-SEP-INQ4JU67KGX5TI3V
-A KUBE-SVC-G2OJTDIWIJ7HQ7MY -m comment --comment "default/mongo:" -j KUBE-SEP-J3MBDOP5WNYLP73O
-A KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -j KUBE-SEP-THKIU3KIDKH63VHE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed May 11 17:06:57 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed May 11 17:06:57 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [419:187638]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [403:197496]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION - [0:0]
:KUBE-SERVICES - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
COMMIT
```

Comment: Hi  - have you ever found a solution for this issue?

Comment: The problem disappeared when using later versions of docker-multi-node and default environment variables.

Comment: I can see you have resolved this issue. Consider posting self answer which will help other users looking at this thread.

Answer (score -2):

sudo to root account, try the curl with root account.